# Extracting data from a list

Tags: python

Hi guys just wondering if it is possible to convert the list below to a dict, i know it is originally a dict but it is showing up now as a list, if it can be converted that would be the easiest method

i have tried `d = dict(zip(*[iter(list[0])]*2))` but this does not work

this is the list :

```
[[{'identityb32': 'qa46imyg4njipjsgpudn7vnn2zub2tec', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '18.238.2.85', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8039e43306e35287a6467d06dfd5add6681d4c82', 'nick': 'Onions', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x809\xe43\x06\xe3R\x87\xa6F}\x06\xdf\xd5\xad\xd6h\x1dL\x82', 'digest': 'lh2LprFLd0bdvtIfPkz58//mgZk', 'pubtime': '09:37:21'}, {'identityb32': 'qbwfsrn3y5mmcnshotg77clvxjufngso', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '109.120.148.60', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '806c5945bbc758c1364774cdff8975ba68569a4e', 'nick': 'Reactor', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80lYE\xbb\xc7X\xc16Gt\xcd\xff\x89u\xbahV\x9aN', 'digest': 'bDAS/RN7q4injGzkIXobcsSwS6c', 'pubtime': '08:55:57'}, {'identityb32': 'qcrds2ps562vf3ctnuoob4lgtmvt4zau', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '195.154.12.66', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '80a23969f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414', 'nick': 'han1', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80\xa29i\xf2\xef\xb5R\xecSm\x1c\xe0\xf1f\x9b+>d\x14', 'digest': 'FoPXNW58WS4eoCWB/eIK7j5yS4E', 'pubtime': '01:09:22'}], [{'identityb32': 'rzjbswyebloufopae2j46a6272wrwlae', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '77.247.181.164', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8e52195b040add42b9e02693cf03dafead1b2c04', 'nick': 'rainbowwarrior', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.5.3-alpha', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eR\x19[\x04\n\xddB\xb9\xe0&\x93\xcf\x03\xda\xfe\xad\x1b,\x04', 'digest': '67A4paMg3mQUqHei8jNSWR2QWsg', 'pubtime': '08:29:31'}, {'identityb32': 'rzniakcq6yj3xdbk766e4yuspkhm2bq2', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '212.116.188.158', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e5a802850f613bb8c2affbc4e62927a8ecd061a', 'nick': '7sYiz', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eZ\x80(P\xf6\x13\xbb\x8c*\xff\xbcNb\x92z\x8e\xcd\x06\x1a', 'digest': '5+O3G9AMJujmUVxO3Fhz7MSPpHI', 'pubtime': '12:34:28'}, {'identityb32': 'rzs3murcnwhdeyj6blsfj7ipltbpmn44', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '176.31.122.216', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e65b652226d8e32613e0ae454fd0f5cc2f6379c', 'nick': 'somewhere', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8ee\xb6R"m\x8e2a>\n\xe4T\xfd\x0f\\\xc2\xf67\x9c', 'digest': 'lEgmmiJcOvzsib9fZjgaxaSG6to', 'pubtime': '03:27:26'}]]
```

if not is there anyway to retrieve data from the list for example to retrieve all the  data related to identityhash for example ?

ideally converting this back to a dict will be the best solution

Thanks

Comment: the inner list contains a dict

Comment: @user29644021, you have more than on sublist so the answer you accepted access just one and ignores all the other dicts in your list.

Comment: @user29644021 you are still only getting half the dicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list=[[{'identityb32': 'qa46imyg4njipjsgpudn7vnn2zub2tec', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '18.238.2.85', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8039e43306e35287a6467d06dfd5add6681d4c82', 'nick': 'Onions', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x809\xe43\x06\xe3R\x87\xa6F}\x06\xdf\xd5\xad\xd6h\x1dL\x82', 'digest': 'lh2LprFLd0bdvtIfPkz58//mgZk', 'pubtime': '09:37:21'}, {'identityb32': 'qbwfsrn3y5mmcnshotg77clvxjufngso', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '109.120.148.60', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '806c5945bbc758c1364774cdff8975ba68569a4e', 'nick': 'Reactor', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80lYE\xbb\xc7X\xc16Gt\xcd\xff\x89u\xbahV\x9aN', 'digest': 'bDAS/RN7q4injGzkIXobcsSwS6c', 'pubtime': '08:55:57'}, {'identityb32': 'qcrds2ps562vf3ctnuoob4lgtmvt4zau', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '195.154.12.66', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '80a23969f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414', 'nick': 'han1', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80\xa29i\xf2\xef\xb5R\xecSm\x1c\xe0\xf1f\x9b+>d\x14', 'digest': 'FoPXNW58WS4eoCWB/eIK7j5yS4E', 'pubtime': '01:09:22'}], [{'identityb32': 'rzjbswyebloufopae2j46a6272wrwlae', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '77.247.181.164', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8e52195b040add42b9e02693cf03dafead1b2c04', 'nick': 'rainbowwarrior', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.5.3-alpha', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eR\x19[\x04\n\xddB\xb9\xe0&\x93\xcf\x03\xda\xfe\xad\x1b,\x04', 'digest': '67A4paMg3mQUqHei8jNSWR2QWsg', 'pubtime': '08:29:31'}, {'identityb32': 'rzniakcq6yj3xdbk766e4yuspkhm2bq2', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '212.116.188.158', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e5a802850f613bb8c2affbc4e62927a8ecd061a', 'nick': '7sYiz', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eZ\x80(P\xf6\x13\xbb\x8c*\xff\xbcNb\x92z\x8e\xcd\x06\x1a', 'digest': '5+O3G9AMJujmUVxO3Fhz7MSPpHI', 'pubtime': '12:34:28'}, {'identityb32': 'rzs3murcnwhdeyj6blsfj7ipltbpmn44', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '176.31.122.216', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e65b652226d8e32613e0ae454fd0f5cc2f6379c', 'nick': 'somewhere', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8ee\xb6R"m\x8e2a>\n\xe4T\xfd\x0f\\\xc2\xf67\x9c', 'digest': 'lEgmmiJcOvzsib9fZjgaxaSG6to', 'pubtime': '03:27:26'}]]
d = {}
for dic in l[0]:
    d.update(dic)
print d
{'identityb32': 'qcrds2ps562vf3ctnuoob4lgtmvt4zau', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'ip': '195.154.12.66', 'orport': '9001', 'digest': 'FoPXNW58WS4eoCWB/eIK7j5yS4E', 'dirport': '9030', 'identityhash': '80a23969f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414', 'nick': 'han1', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80\xa29i\xf2\xef\xb5R\xecSm\x1c\xe0\xf1f\x9b+>d\x14', 'pubtime': '01:09:22'}
```

You have more than one sublist in your list so you may need to zip and update,
but with  you having  dicts using the same keys so you will be losing certain values when you update to a new dict.

If you want to flatten all the dicts into a single list you and create multiple dicts to keep all the values or get whatever keys values you need in a list comp:

```
flattened= ([x for y in  l for x in y])
```

This will   get all the hashes from all dicts:

```
print [x.get('identityhash') for x in flattened]

['8039e43306e35287a6467d06dfd5add6681d4c82', '806c5945bbc758c1364774cdff8975ba68569a4e', '80a23969f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414', '8e52195b040add42b9e02693cf03dafead1b2c04', '8e5a802850f613bb8c2affbc4e62927a8ecd061a', '8e65b652226d8e32613e0ae454fd0f5cc2f6379c']
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated.

Comment: @NateMara, there are more elements in the list, not just one dict, you are just accessing one.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1):

You will lose data if you combine the dicts, as the inner list contains multiple dicts with the same keys. If you just want the identity hashes in a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [[{'identityb32': 'qa46imyg4njipjsgpudn7vnn2zub2tec', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '18.238.2.85', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8039e43306e35287a6467d06dfd5add6681d4c82', 'nick': 'Onions', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x809\xe43\x06\xe3R\x87\xa6F}\x06\xdf\xd5\xad\xd6h\x1dL\x82', 'digest': 'lh2LprFLd0bdvtIfPkz58//mgZk', 'pubtime': '09:37:21'}, {'identityb32': 'qbwfsrn3y5mmcnshotg77clvxjufngso', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '109.120.148.60', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '806c5945bbc758c1364774cdff8975ba68569a4e', 'nick': 'Reactor', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80lYE\xbb\xc7X\xc16Gt\xcd\xff\x89u\xbahV\x9aN', 'digest': 'bDAS/RN7q4injGzkIXobcsSwS6c', 'pubtime': '08:55:57'}, {'identityb32': 'qcrds2ps562vf3ctnuoob4lgtmvt4zau', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '195.154.12.66', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '80a23969f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414', 'nick': 'han1', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x80\xa29i\xf2\xef\xb5R\xecSm\x1c\xe0\xf1f\x9b+>d\x14', 'digest': 'FoPXNW58WS4eoCWB/eIK7j5yS4E', 'pubtime': '01:09:22'}], [{'identityb32': 'rzjbswyebloufopae2j46a6272wrwlae', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '80', 'ip': '77.247.181.164', 'orport': '443', 'identityhash': '8e52195b040add42b9e02693cf03dafead1b2c04', 'nick': 'rainbowwarrior', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.5.3-alpha', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eR\x19[\x04\n\xddB\xb9\xe0&\x93\xcf\x03\xda\xfe\xad\x1b,\x04', 'digest': '67A4paMg3mQUqHei8jNSWR2QWsg', 'pubtime': '08:29:31'}, {'identityb32': 'rzniakcq6yj3xdbk766e4yuspkhm2bq2', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '212.116.188.158', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e5a802850f613bb8c2affbc4e62927a8ecd061a', 'nick': '7sYiz', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.3.25', 'flags': ['Exit', 'Fast', 'Guard', 'HSDir', 'Named', 'Running', 'Stable', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8eZ\x80(P\xf6\x13\xbb\x8c*\xff\xbcNb\x92z\x8e\xcd\x06\x1a', 'digest': '5+O3G9AMJujmUVxO3Fhz7MSPpHI', 'pubtime': '12:34:28'}, {'identityb32': 'rzs3murcnwhdeyj6blsfj7ipltbpmn44', 'pubdate': '2014-07-07', 'dirport': '9030', 'ip': '176.31.122.216', 'orport': '9001', 'identityhash': '8e65b652226d8e32613e0ae454fd0f5cc2f6379c', 'nick': 'somewhere', 'version': 'Tor 0.2.4.22', 'flags': ['Fast', 'HSDir', 'Running', 'Stable', 'Unnamed', 'V2Dir', 'Valid'], 'identity': '\x8ee\xb6R"m\x8e2a>\n\xe4T\xfd\x0f\\\xc2\xf67\x9c', 'digest': 'lEgmmiJcOvzsib9fZjgaxaSG6to', 'pubtime': '03:27:26'}]]
>>> identityhash = [i.get('identityhash') for j in data for i in j]
>>> print(identityhash)
['8039e43306e35287a6467d06dfd5add6681d4c82','806c5945bbc758c1364774cdff8975ba68569a4e','80a269f2efb552ec536d1ce0f1669b2b3e6414','8e52195b040add42b9e02693cf03dafead1b2c04','8e5a802850f6bb8c2affbc4e62927a8ecd061a','8e65b652226d8e32613e0ae454fd0f5cc2f6379c']
```

Comment: there are more that data[0][0] dicts in the list so you do need a loop.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I see that now.

Comment: still not accessing all dicts

Comment: Should now be accessing all dicts

Comment: now you have flattened the list as I already had in my answer ;)

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @user2962401 hmm. I just copied and pasted the code in my answer, and I'm not getting that error. Are you sure you didn't mistype something?